# UIImageView not appearing

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am trying to work with a UIImageView programmatically and can't get it to appear on the screen.  In my header I have the following lines:

```
@interface myClass : UIView {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Then in my `viewWillAppear` I have the following:

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 72, 72);
self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test-image.png"]];
[containerView addSubview:self.imageView];
```

And this doesn't work at all.  If I add the following lines in `viewWillAppear` I can get a UIImageView to appear:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button_bg.png"]];
[containerView addSubview:imgView];
```

So I can't make sense of why instantiating a UIImageView would work but using the class's ivar would not.  What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate all objects. One way to do it, if you want to keep a reference to imageView around, is...(don't forget to release it in dealloc).

```
 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button_bg.png"]];
[containerView addSubview:imageView];
```

You can work out the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take the IBOutlet away and add:

```
self.imageView = [[ImageView alloc]...]
```

Comment: You can probably take the whole @property line also away if the image is only used in myClass.